# Get CPU usage each Google Cloud Run instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I would like to get the CPU usage for each Cloud Run instance. I can find the CPU usage aggregated for all instances in the Metrics Explorer but I can't split per instance :(. Any ideas?

Comment: Use Cloud Monitoring and filter by instance ID

Comment: On the Container CPU Utilization metric, I don't see instance ID in the filtering list (https://imgur.com/a/8fuQz3t).

Comment: My bad, you can't have the instance_id with standard metrics, it's only with custom metrics. Therefore, I don't know!

Comment: Hope someone from Google will see this post.

Comment: I will ask directly the engineering team ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Let me summarize the discussion with Googlers*

There is no out-of-the-box solution even if Google is aware about the usefulness for troubleshooting. Technically, they cannot do it for every instance due to the very high cardinality of the instanceID label.

The current workaround is to use OTEL (Open Telemetry), a sidecar collector and Google Managed services for Prometheus to get this additional custom metric.

https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/tutorials/custom-metrics-opentelemetry-sidecar